# Python creating a lists of lists of floats from a single list of strings

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

I'm new to python and I need to create a list of lists (a matrix) of float values from a list of strings. So if my input is:

```
objectListData = ["1, 2, 3, 4", "5, 6, 7, 8", "9, 0, 0, 7", "5, 4, 3, 2", "2, 3, 3, 3", "2, 2, 3, 3"]
```

what I want to obtain is:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 0, 7], [5, 4, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 3, 3]]
```

Here's my code:

```
objectListData = ["1, 2, 3, 4", "5, 6, 7, 8", "9, 0, 0, 7", "5, 4, 3, 2", "2, 3, 3, 3", "2, 2, 3, 3"]


objectListDataFloats = [[0] * len(objectListData[0].split(', '))] * len(objectListData)
for count in range(1,len(objectListData)):
    for ii in range(1,len(objectListData[count].split(', '))):
        objectListDataFloats[count][ii] = float(objectListData[count].split(', ')[ii])

print objectListDataFloats

objectListDataFloats=[[0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0], [0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0], [0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0], [0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0], [0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0], [0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]]
```

where is the error? I can't find it. Thanks

Comment: In addition to the problems Sukrit Kalra's answers points out: Whenever you find yourself doing `for i in range(len(foo))`, you're probably doing it wrong. If you just want each value in `foo`, just do `for value in foo`. If you need the index as well as the value, do `for index, value in enumerate(foo)`. Either way, you completely avoid the potential for off-by-one errors (like the one you actually have in your code), and make everything simpler and more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your inner lists are references to one single list and not individual lists.

```
>>> objectListDataFloats = [[0] * len(objectListData[0].split(', '))] * len(objectListData)

>>> objectListDataFloats
[[0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
>>> id(objectListDataFloats[0]) == id(objectListDataFloats[1])
True
```

After you fix that, you need to iterate from the starting index of `0`, since the lists in Python start their index from 0.

```
for count in range(len(objectListData)):
    for ii in range(len(objectListData[count].split(', '))):
        objectListDataFloats[count][ii] = float(objectListData[count].split(', ')[ii])


>>> objectListDataFloats
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0], [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]]
```

To completely do away with the initial initialization of the list with zeroes, you could also just build the list as you go along, something like

```
>>> objectListDataFloats = []
>>> for elem in objectListData:
        test_list = []
        for val in elem.split(','):
            test_list.append(float(val))
        objectListDataFloats.append(test_list)


>>> objectListDataFloats
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0], [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]]
```

You don't need to iterate over the list or a string by using indices, you can just iterate over the list like in the above example.

**Reduced Solution** -

You could just reduce the whole solution to the following though (Change `int` to `float` if you require floating point numbers)

```
>>> objectListData = ["1, 2, 3, 4", "5, 6, 7, 8", "9, 0, 0, 7", "5, 4, 3, 2", "2, 3, 3, 3", "2, 2, 3, 3"]
>>> [map(int, elem.split(',')) for elem in objectListData]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 0, 7], [5, 4, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 3, 3]]
```

Answer (score 4):

Here ya go:

```
[[int(y) for y in x.split(",")] for x in objectListData]
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 0, 0, 7], [5, 4, 3, 2], [2, 3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 3, 3]]
```

or, if you want floats:

```
[[float(y) for y in x.split(",")] for x in objectListData]
```

output:

```
[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0], [5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], [9.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0], [5.0, 4.0, 3.0, 2.0], [2.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0], [2.0, 2.0, 3.0, 3.0]]
```

Comment: He describes his input as a matrix of float values, so assuming that every digit is a separate number seems unwarranted. Especially since it's unnecessary, given that the numbers are obviously comma-separated.